# Angular: Refresh breadcrumb if the language is changed

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

The users can change the language in their settings. Now I've seen that when I change the language, the breadcrumb isn't translated. The breadcrumb is translated first when I move to another page.

My question is now, how I can refresh the breadcrumb items when I change the language, that they are translated immediately and not at first when I move to another page.

I set the breadcrumb items display value directly in the [name].module.ts files like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SettingsOverviewComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginService],
  },
  {
    path: "profile",
    component: UserProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginService],
    data: {breadcrumb: "accountAdministration"}
  },
  {
    path: "allUsers",
    component: UsersComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginService],
    data: {breadcrumb: "allUsers"}
  },
];
```

Anyone have an idea?